# Firefox add-on : extension icon not showing

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on developing a Firefox add-on using the `Add-on SDK`. My extension is working fine when using SDK, but when I create the `.xpi` file to add it manually to the browser, it does not show the extension icon.

I tried to change the icon path in the `package.json` file, but still it didn't shows the icon.

package.json file:

```
{...
  "icon"        : "Phone-icon48.png",
  "icon64"      : "Phone-icon64.png",
...}
```

Widget panel used to display icon:

```
WidgetPackage.Widget({
  label: "Phone Dial",
  id: "phone_dial",
  contentURL: data.url("images/Phone-icon19.png"),
  panel: panel_name
});
```

Can anyone help me resolve the issue?

Thank You.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - is the icon missing for the widget, in the addon manager, both? For the widget icon, does the file actually exist in your add-on project at 'data/images/Phone-icon19.png'???

Comment: Yes, the icon is missing for the widget, but it is missing only when the extension is added using the .xpi file. when I run extension using the 'cfx run' the icon is showing. The phone icon image is exist in the data directory.

Comment: I have the same problem. And the icon do shows in the add-ons manager.

Answer (score 3):

[This may be a persistent bug](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/197).  [This thread reports a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533775/icon-not-showing-in-firefox-add-on-manager?rq=1).

Ah - here is the solution.
You put your icons in a folder called `data` in the root of your addon's directory and call them `as if` they were in root.

```
{...
    icon: { "16": "./icon-16.png", "32":"./icon-32.png", "64": "./icon-64.png" },
...}
```

When I did this then the icons show up in the toolbars.  It isn't very clear, but if you piece things together, [you *might* deduce that from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Addon SDK docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#icon):

> The relative path from the root of the add-on to a PNG file containing the icon for the add-on. Defaults to "icon.png".

So your package.json should look like this:

```
{...
  "icon"        : "data/images/Phone-icon48.png",
  "icon64"      : "data/images/Phone-icon64.png",
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

[A seemingly related issue](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/197) was closed earlier, yet it happens to me today

A workaround with jpm 1.1.4 and Firefox 48/50:

- Name the icon `icon.png` and place it in *root dir* of addon.
- Write *no* `"icon": ...` entry in package.json (thus no `<em:icon>` in install.rdf)