# Icon not showing in firefox add-on manager

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a new Firefox add-on with the following directory structure:

```
/
   package.json
   data/
       icons/
           icon48.png
```

In my package.json file I have this:

```
 "icon": "data/icons/icon48.png",
```

(among other things). When I run `jpm run` as recommended by the Firefox add-on docs, the extension loads but the icon is not visible in the add-on manager. Any idea what I'm missing? I have been referencing this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#icon, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: "asked 2 hours ago", I found this because I'm having the exact same problem. Right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug. See this [issue](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/197) in the `jpm` repository.

For me, moving the icon image to the root directory (i.e. the same path as `package.json`) and renaming it "icon.png" fixed the problem.

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I still have this bug with jpm 1.0.6 version. I solved it adding the next icon path:

```
{

  "id": "jid1-AKuBexDY5zJsIQ@jetpack",
  "icon": "resource://jid1-akubexdy5zjsiq-at-jetpack/data/images/icon48.png",

}
```

Note that the "path" is similar to the "id" field but there are not capital letters

Comment: It works with capital letters too, the only trick is to change `@` for `-at-` in the id. Thanks!