# Firefox extension not showing icons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I have implemented sample mozilla firefox extension to display firefox icon (action button) on toolbar and it will open "http://www.mozilla.org/".
It is working fine in jpm run, then I have created package of that using jpm xpi and created xpi file. Then I have installed it in my firefox browser and successfully installed but did not work. **It couldn't add firefox icon (action button) on toolbar** (There is no error in console).

Below is the code.

**index.js**

```js
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("http://www.mozilla.org/");
}
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "title": "Sample",
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Sample AddOn",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Sample",
  "engines": {
    "firefox": ">=30.0a1",
    "fennec": ">=30.0a1"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I have implemented that using - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Is the profile you are using set to never remember history (Options -> Privacy -> History), or otherwise in [private browsing mode](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/private-browsing/).  If so, see [Firefox add-on works with “jpm run”, but not whith .xpi file generated with “jpm xpi”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38793196/3773011).

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the icons visable, you have to create a `data` directory inside your extension and put your icons there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought that Id is not required for JPM. But anyways I have tried it with Id, but still the same issue is there. I am not sure if that issue is regarding JPM or not, becuase I am not using CFX. Please advice.

Comment: You are right, the `id` is not required for `jpm`. I run your code with jpm and again there is no error and the extension works fine for me. Are you sure that you are not getting any error when you try `jpm xpi`?

Comment: Yes, There is no error in jpm xpi. As well jpm run is also working fine but when I installed xpi file in my firefox, nothing happen means it doesn't display icon. Can you please send me the xpi file which you have generated? - pateljb90@gmail.com

Comment: Now I understand your question and I edited my answer. Plz let me know if the problem still remains. If it is still a problem then I will send you the `xpi`

Comment: Yes, I did create directory "data", and added icon to that folder. You can send me the xpi. Thanks.

Comment: @JigarLakhani Have you found a solution? I seem to have the same problem.

Comment: For some reason, the add-on only works for me as long as private mode is not turned on...

Comment: This is the right answer - you put the icons in a folder called `data` - but you call them in the script as if they were at root: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34322550/1038866

Answer (score 0):

You missed one of item in this lesson...
You need to create "data" directory in your extension root dir, and all of content you have to put in this folder.
In my Example I use it like this:

```
var button = this.buttons.ActionButton({
            id: "show-panel",
            label: "Show Panel",
            icon: {
                "16": "./icon/x16.png",
                "32": "./icon/x32.png",
                "64": "./icon/x64.png"
            },
            onClick: function(state) {
              // ...
            }
        });
```

and my structure looks like:
MyExtensionName/data/icon/[*.png,*.ico]

But you can also use internal links of your extension:

resource://extensionname/...

```
icon: {
  "16": "resource://extensionname/data/icon/x16.png",
  "32": "resource://extensionname/data/icon/x32.png",
  "64": "resource://extensionname/data/icon/x64.png"
}
```