# Firefox add-on works with "jpm run", but not whith .xpi file generated with "jpm xpi"

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using the [Firefox Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK) to develop a Firefox add-on.
I have followed the [Getting Started tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)).

Firefox version : 41.0.2
My Process is :

1. `jpm run` --> OK the add-on works fine
2. `jpm xpi` --> OK : Create *@myAddon.xpi* (JPM [info] Successfully created *.xpi* at ...)
3. Use of *@myAddon.xpi* --> NOK
   When I tried to install the add-on  in my Firefox ( Add-on -> install from file -> *@myAddon.xpi* ), I have a message "Install successfully". Looks good. BUT, the add-on doesn't work. Nothing happens.

So, why is the test with `jpm run` OK, but does not work after installing the `.xpi` file???

I can share the code with you, but how can this situation happen? If it works in test, I expect that it works in "release".
I get no error or warning.

High Level :

## *Index.js*:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.11.3.min.js"), data.url("./Compute.js")],
    onAttach: function (worker) {
        var currentUrl = tabs.activeTab.url;
        param = currentUrl;
        Request({
            url: param,
            onComplete: function (response) {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response.text);
                worker.port.emit('got-request', parsed);
            }
        }).get();
    }
```

## *data/Compute.js*

```
self.port.on('got-request', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Edit (moved from comments):
I find something interesting.... Depending on the level of privacy in FireFox the addon will work or not. ( Options->Privacy->History "Remember history " or "Never remember history") - Remember history " --> addOn OK - "Never remember history" --> addOn NOK Any idea why

Comment: I find something interesting....
Depending on the level of privacy in FireFox the addon will work or not.
( Options->Privacy->History "Remember history " or "Never remember history") 
- Remember history "         --> addOn OK
- "Never remember history" --> addOn NOK
Any idea why ?

Comment: code snippet looks ok. upload the add-on to github and share the link.

Comment: @user5023028 yes by default, jpm addons dont work in private mode. You have to add a key to your package.json to work in private mode.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works with: "permissions": {"private-browsing": true}, added in package.json

Comment: This question is off-topic because:
It is a debugging question which does not contain the information needed to diagnose the issue.
The comments make it clear the issue was the lack of a permission being set in the *package.json* file which is not included in the question. Thus, the question requires guessing at information not provided.
I'm using a custom reason because it does contain code, just not all the code necessary. Thus, it is hard for people to see that it is actually off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

As you have determined, if you desire your Firefox Add-on SDK add-on to work in [Private Browsing mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/private-browsing) you need to have add the key `private-browsing` with a value of `true` in your [*package.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json) file.

If you are using no other [permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#Key_reference), you could add a line to your *package.json* file that looks like:

```
"permissions": {"private-browsing": true}
```

The [Firefox documentation on writing SDK add-ons for private browsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/private-browsing) mode specifically states that the [`require("sdk/private-browsing").isPrivate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/private-browsing#isPrivate(object)) method will return true when any of the following is the case (emphasis mine):

> - a private window, or
> - a tab belonging to a private window, or
> - a worker that's associated with a document hosted in a private window
> - **any window, tab, or worker if the browser has been configured to never remember history (Options->Privacy->History)**

If you do not have `"private-browsing": true`, then, as the [documentation states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/private-browsing), the following will be the case (emphasis mine):

> - the [windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows) module will not list any private browser windows, generate any events for private browser windows, or let the add-on open any private browser windows
> - the [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) module will not list any tabs that belong to private browser windows, and the add-on won't receive any events for such tabs
> - **any [ui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui) components will not be displayed in private browser windows**
> - any menus or menu items created using the [context-menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) will not be shown in context menus that belong to private browser windows
> - the [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) module will not attach content scripts to documents belonging to private browser windows
> - any [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel) objects will not be shown if the active window is a private browser window
> - the [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/selection) module will not include any selections made in private browser windows

The net effect will be that your add-on will appear to not work when the profile you are using is configured to never remember history without having the `"private-browsing": true` permission in your *package.json*.

If you do put that permission in your *package.json* file, you must use the private-browsing module, `require("sdk/private-browsing").isPrivate(object)`, to check for being in a private window or tab.  If you are in such a window or tab you need to not store any information about such environment.