# Firefox addon - icon not showing

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I'm trying to write an Addon for Firefox. For this I'm using the Mozilla "Addon-SDK".

When i use the "jpm run" function all works well. But as soon as i package it to an xpi and install it, the icon wont show up in the toolbar. This seems to be a bug in the SDK.
I have tried various workaround solutions from other blog posts.

- Editing package.json
- renaming to "icon"
- moving to data
- Moving the icon to root
- Absolute paths
- editing the firefox version in rdf
- debuging Index.js...

Here the most useful:

[Firefox add-on : extension icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386429/firefox-add-on-extension-icon-not-showing)
https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/197

Since Firefox 43 addons must be verifyed. I did this. I also disabled the function in about:config so i could try new versions faster. Still no luck.

Here is my code in **index.js**:  *Edited according to answer but still not working*

```
    var button = buttons.ActionButton(
    {
      id: "MorastLink",
      label: "In den Morast",
      icon:
      {
        "16": "./images/icon16.png",
        "32": "./images/icon32.png",
        "64": "./images/icon64.png"
      },
    onClick: CopyToMorast
    });
```

Here I also tried, moving the path, changing names, using absolute path...

And this is my **package.json**

```
    {
      "title": "Morast",
      "name": "morastaddon",
      "version": "0.1.4",
      "description": "An Addon to insert a \"Add to Morast\" button on distributer sites.",
      "main": "index.js",
      "author": "Lisa Austen",
      "icon": "ressource://@morastaddon/data/images/icon16.png",
      "icon64": "ressource://@morastaddon/data/images/icon64.png",
      "engines": {
      "firefox": ">=38.0a1",
      "fennec": ">=38.0a1" },
      "license": "MIT",
      "keywords": [
      "jetpack"
    ]
    }
```

https://github.com/LAusten/MorastAddon.git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox extension not showing icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941591/firefox-extension-not-showing-icons)

Comment: I have tried that. It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#ActionButton%28options%29), the icon path has to be relative to the `data` folder:

> - as a resource:// URL pointing at an icon file in your add-on's "data" directory, typically constructed using self.data.url(iconfile)
> - as a relative path: **a string in the form "./iconfile", where "iconfile" is a relative path to the icon file beginning in your add-on's "data" directory**

Example:

```
  icon:
  {
    "16": "./images/icon16.png",
    "32": "./images/icon32.png",
    "64": "./images/icon64.png"
  }
```

Comment: I tried this in `index.js`, sadly it didn't work. I set the icon path in `package.json` as describet here: [Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#icon) ` "icon": "ressource://@morastaddon/data/images/icon16.png"`

Comment: It works for me in Firefox 43 (using the code from your GitHub repository and "./images" for the paths). You might try restarting the browser and see if that helps.

Comment: Weird, I installed Firefox on another Computer and there it works. Same version of Firefox, the only difference is, that i have quite a few addons installed on this one.  
Anyway, thanks for the help.