# firefox extension: Can't add an icon to a button

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have this block of code for a button I am adding to the tab right-click context menu

```
var playButton = doc.createElementNS(ns,"button");
playButton.setAttribute("id", "contexttab-newtab");
playButton.setAttribute("label", _("newtab_string"));
playButton.setAttribute("accesskey", _("newtabaccesskey_string"));
playButton.setAttribute("oncommand", "BrowserOpenTab();");
playButton.setAttribute("icon", "./icon-16.png");
```

However, it shows no button. The icon itself is located in `data/icon-16.png` as I believe it should be. 'image' doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of button-less context menu]

Pastebin of full code: http://pastebin.com/4FeZSScy

Comment: Try using attribute `image` instead of `icon` and also use full path to your file.

Comment: I've tried both of those things with no change. The pathname is correct as per [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386429/firefox-add-on-extension-icon-not-showing?rq=1).

Comment: Can you post a link to yoru github or some place where we can see this code. I have to see more of the context,

Comment: pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/4FeZSScy